# Connecting two monitors when only one VGA port

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I have a computer with only one VGA port. I have connected one monitor to the VGA port. I want to connect another monitor to the computer. The computer doesn't have any other graphics outputs.

What I need to install in the computer to attach a second monitor?
Do I need to buy new graphics card? Or can I get DVI or Displayport card?

Comment: You are confusing, CPU and computer. What do you want to do ? Why do you want DVI ? Which computer do you use ?

Comment: @Vouze: I haven't mentioned computer in my question!!! For that did I get downvote?

Comment: You have a CPU with a VGA port? I've never seen that. I've seen PC's with VGA, servers with VGA, even mobile phones with VGA, but never a chip with a VGA connector. How do they mount the connector on the chip package?

Comment: A downvote is a bit harsh, but I can understand why some people get anoyed. I usually edit the post to correct CPU ( A chip like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Intel_80486DX2_top.jpg) to desktop (A case with motherboard, CPU chip, power supply, graphical card, etc etc).

Comment: +1 your use of the term CPU is not technically wrong and you don't deserve any downvote for it. It's just an old and somewhat obsolete usage that people here are not familiar with, so i'd say they're more wrong than you for saying you're confusing your terms.

Comment: @barlop: Wikipedia seems to suggest that using CPU for the actual chip has been around for some time: *The term has been used in the computer industry at least since the early 1960s.[1] Traditionally, the term "CPU" refers to a processor, more specifically to its processing unit and control unit (CU), distinguishing these core elements of a computer from external components such as main memory and I/O circuitry.[2]* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit

Comment: @mtak Nothing I said contradicted what you mention wikipedia saying - i'm not saying that CPU later came to  mean processor - what I am saying is that using CPU to mean the box, is an old usage, seen in old textbooks, but not seen nowadays(in books or technical sources) - that is not to say that CPU to mean processor is not a usage that goes way back to old times too.

Comment: Does your computer have any USB3 ports? What is form-factor of this computer? Desktop, ultra-ITX, NUC, etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignoreing all the terminology:

You only have one graphic output atm, with an analog signal and a DB15 connector.
You want to connect multiple monitors.

There are two ways to do that:

1. Add a graphics card with more outputs. For non gaming purposes a cheap (€80-ish) card with 2 or 3 outputs will do just fine, and you can use both these and the current DB15/VGA connector.
2. Split the output from your current DB15/VGA over multiple screens.

The last will mean you have the same image on both screens. Might be useful in a classroom with one image on the screen and an other on a projector.

The first option seems much more sensible. Adding more graphics outputs can be done with PCI-e cards (simple, works at boot, usually provides modern outputs which means you can use a modern monitor). If at all possible I would go for a second monitor with display port and a cheap card with a pair of display port outs.

Note that even one DP out can be used to chain to multiple monitors as long as all use DP 1.2 and MST.

A more portable solution is an USB based external card. This sounds great, but performace is much lower and the sole experience I have with that (one USB card on two laptops) is awful. Graphical artifacts, no screen updating if you rotate it 90 degrees, blue screens, etc etc. That might be just bad luck with a USB32HDEH but it makes me reluctant to advice this route.

Answer (score 5):

Okay so you have a few options, if you have another video out point like a **DVI or HDMI** you can connect a monitor using that, if you dont have any left then you can either go out and by a **USB to VGA connector** which displays the second screen. beware that using this is very slow and can be jittery if you dont buy a high quality converter. You can also go out an buy **another graphics card** which will be more stable and secure than using a converter.

Answer (score 3):

A second graphics card or if you don't mind the same thing on both screens, then a VGA splitter.

I want to bring up an important point that others have missed regarding your use of the term CPU.

In old textbooks, the term CPU did indeed refer to the box.

But it's a bit of an ambiguous term, because since then people have used the term to mean processor, and that's a more common usage. And most people aren't aware of the old usage of CPU to mean the box.

So you could just call the thing you're calling a CPU, a/the box.(e.g. the case + what's in it). e.g. people refer to windows boxes.  And call a processor a processor rather than a CPU.. That way you can avoid the term CPU entirely because it's ambiguous.. But know that when people use the term CPU, they usually mean processor and aren't aware of any other meaning of it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **CPU** = **C**entral **P**rocessing **U**nit, not computer. If your graphic card doesn't have second port there are two options:

1. Change your graphic card on card with 2 video ports
2. Buy second graphic card (requires free pci slot on motherboard)

Comment: -1 Your first sentence isn't really right. CPU can mean the box, if you look at old textbookx you'd see they refer to it as that.. IF you know that then you should mention that and add some nuance to your first sentence, and if you didn't know that then you'd see how your first sentence is kind of wrong.