# Didn't detect another display when using 2 monitors with VGA splitter

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga

I have a desktop without graphics card and I just bought a VGA 2 port 200 MHz VGA splitter. I have a LG monitor as primary and viewsonic VA1912wb monitor as seconday.

when using the VGA splitter, the second screen is mirroring the first one, instead of extending.
In settings > Display > Multiple Display > Detect button throws the error : Didn't detect another display.

Comment: What is the splitter model?

Comment: As I recall, VGA doesn't actually support "splitting" to use two monitors on one port; to have two VGA monitors act as a single large desktop, you'd need separate VGA ports on a video card that supports them, or two standard single-monitor VGA video cards. Most VGA 'splitters' that I have encountered were essentially "wire splitters" so that you could e.g., use a small screen on the desk to see (and control) what you were presenting conveniently while using a large screen or projection screen to present to others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting two monitors when only one VGA port](https://superuser.com/questions/1121860/connecting-two-monitors-when-only-one-vga-port)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A VGA splitter will not, on its own, enable your operating system to use two monitors independently.

You will need a dual-output graphics card for that.

It can also be done by using certain software, though this may offer more limited support.

There's more info in [this article](https://thetechnologyland.com/does-the-vga-splitter-allow-you-to-get-an-extended-desktop/).